# How to make a input field focused after the site is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very simple one page website that has a input field in it. I want to make the input field focused when the window/site is loaded so that the user/visitor can start typing on it right away the site is loaded!

I want it NOT IN JQUERY. IF POSSIBLE PLEASE GIVE ME A SOLUTION IN JAVASCRIPT PLEASE.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new input field attribute call `autofocus`. Supported by all browsers except IE
http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-autofocus.php

You can use that and provide fallback with the solutions others are providing

```
var i = document.createElement('input');
if(!('autofocus' in i)) {
   window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById('ID').focus();
   });
}
```

Comment: It worked...the most easiest solution! I don't need IE support at all. Thanks...you are the winner :)

Answer (score 4):

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById('ID').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

//ID is the id of textbox

```
document.getElementById('ID').focus();
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a pound sign?

Comment: @veeTrain, sorry, pound sign is not needed. I am a jQuery lover so I put it there by habit:)

Comment: Not a problem; I presumed as much :-)

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById("ControlID").focus();

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the onLoad callback so that it will focus after the page has been loaded:

`<body onLoad="function() { document.getElementById('input_field_id').focus(); }">`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `focus()` method in javascript.

In body onload method, call the javascript method, where you need to set the focus on the input field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load()
{
   document.getElementById("inputFieldId").focus();
}
</script>
<body onload="load()">
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has autofocus attribute for this job. You could check from [here](http://wufoo.com/html5/attributes/02-autofocus.html) if your target browser(s) has support for this attribute.